# AWS Creating Autoscaling group failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I am unable to create an new environment(worker in an environment) in beanstalk. I understand that the error says the limit is reached but unable to figure out where the error lies.

AutoScaling Groups
[image]

Instances
[image]

Limits
[image]

Stack named '' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].

Creating Auto Scaling group named:  failed. 
Reason: Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Auto Scaling activity failed 49 seconds ago with error: Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1. Launching EC2 instance failed. At 2019-07-07T20:09:19Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1. Initialization completed 89 seconds ago and took 51 seconds. There are no instances. Auto Scaling group desired capacity is set to 1.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **Limits** tab in the EC2 management console.

There is a default limit of 20 concurrent instances per region. There are also limits per Instance Type.

You can request the limits to be increased.

Comment: Limit on Running On-Demand t2.micro instances = 2 is what's showing in my limits tab.

I already had "4"(including the one that stopped working) t2.micro instances running from a long time but it suddenly started showing the error mentioned above. I at most have 8-10 running instances spread in 2 regions.
Could it be because of the instance size limit?

Comment: Yes, the error suggests that it has hit the limit. You should request a limit increase.